# Adding splitplot (dotplot) to grouped boxplot - Panda and Seaborn

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, boxplot, seaborn

I am using seaborn for first time, and trying to make a nested (grouped) boxplot with data-points added as dots. Here is my code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.set(style="ticks")
## Draw a nested boxplot to show bills by day and sex
sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",data=tips,width=0.5,palette="PRGn",linewidth=1)

## Draw a split strip plot
sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",palette="PRGn",data=tips,size=4,edgecolor="gray",
             split=True)
sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True)
plt.show()
```

And the figure:[image]

You see that dots are not centered to boxes, because of the 'width' parameter used in boxplots. Is there any way I can align dots to boxes? The width parameter in boxplot command is the reason for unaligned dots.

p.s. - I have added the MCVE as mentioned by tom.

Bade

Comment: in the example towards the bottom of [this page](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html) they seem to be centred (although on a horizontal, not vertical, plot). Perhaps you could add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question that reproduces this behaviour?

Comment: @tom: I added the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance between groups is computed automatically and there's no simple way to change it that I am aware of, but you are using an indirect way to modify it in the boxplot: the keyword `width`. Use the default value and everything will align.

```
sns.set(style="ticks")
sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips,
            palette="PRGn", linewidth=1)
sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker", data=tips,
              palette="PRGn", size=4, edgecolor="gray", split=True)
sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True)
```

[image: aligned plot]